# Multiple Instances on Back pressed

Tags: android, button, back, instances

I have an audio player which has two main activities. 
1.The splash Activity for loading splash page and another for the player.When I press the back button and select my app from the launcher multiple instances of the activities are happening.

Splash Activity-Player-Another Splash Activity-Another player-Another splash activity-Another player
A-B-A`-B`-A`-B`
If I clicked play in all 3 player activities 3 songs will be playing in background.

It is only happening when the back button is pressed.
It is not happening when you are pressed the home button.

So as a simple solution for the time being I have disabled the back button.

May I get a solution from anybody.

Answer (score 1):

You can write in your manifest file

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

In activity tag

```
<activity
    android:name=".HomeActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent ip = new Intent(this, YourMainActivity.class);
    startActivity(ip);
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Not working.It is calling my player activity(multiple instances) again again while pressing back button & also the music of first player activity is already playing in the background.

Comment: replace YourMainActivity with the activity which does not contain mediaplayer

Comment: before player activity only was coming. Now splashactivity(mainactivity) following player activity is coming.Where the song plays in background and player activity is a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

and http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

If you can show some code, it would be easier to figure out exact issue.